# How do I access properties on this object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, object

I am working in node.js and socket.io, basically I listen for a socket `disconnect` event and call a method. `app.update()`

```
socket.on('disconnect', function (data) {
    app.update();
});

// This is in another file, and the id is static, but I am more concered with the
// messages object that is passed through.
update: function() {
    models.Message.find({_id: "532c8d9ce889ed4c21538630"}, function(err, messages) {
        console.log(messages)
    });
}
```

This is what the `messages` object looks like

```
[ { username: 'Marcus',                                         
    connected: true,                                            
    _id: 532c8d9ce889ed4c21538630,                              
    __v: 0 } ]
```

I am not sure how to access an object with the brackets around it, but basically I want to update the object so that I can set `connected` to false.

I tried `messages['connected']`.

Answer (score 3):

You've got an array of objects.  So you need to access the first element of the array, and then the 'connected' property.  Do this:

```
messages[0].connected = false;
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an example that changed connected to false, perfect.

Answer (score 3):

`messages` may contain more than one result, so you have an array there.

Actually `messages` will always be an array because you're using `find`, which expects multiple results. If you used `findOne` instead it wouldn't be an array but a document.

You should try for example.. `messages[0].username`

Comment: Ah thanks I remember seeing the `findOne` in the mongodb docs. I forgot about it. And I can't believe I could be so dumb, brackets pretty much always represent an array. I was just confused why it was returning an array it didn't make sense. Now it does! Thanks!

Comment: by the way, be sure to add mongodb and nodejs as tags to this post

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update each one of them:

```
messages.forEach(function(message) {
    message.connected = false;
});
```